# I have issue with saving form: add_product to be specific in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to save simple form add_product, I don't have any error but the new product doesn't appear in admin or on a page. I really not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestion would be great! Thank you.

my views.py

```
def add_product(request):
    author = request.user
    product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
    if product_form.is_valid():
        form = product_form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/')
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'products/add_product.html', {'product_form': product_form})
```

my forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'picture',)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.all, name='all'),
url(r'^add/$', views.add_product, name='add_product'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.single_product, name='single_product'),
```

)

template: products/add_product.html

```
<h1>Add Product</h1>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ product_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/picture/', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('single_product', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my view.py by adding following line :
    form.author = request.user

and I removed the first line : author = request.user plus the instance as well.

So now works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be valid. And there should be errors.
The first thing that is notice is following:

```
author = request.user
product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
```

You are passing user instance as a instance to author form. That doesnt make any sense. For product form instance should a product, not a user.  If you want to set a author field you can do following :

```
form = product_form.save(commit=False)
form.author = author 
form.save()
```

Also its not good to call this variable form, because its not a form anymore, its a product object that is returned by save function.

Comment: yes you right, it didn't make sense to me as well, I will update the code according to your suggestion and will see what happen.

Comment: I removed author = request.user and I added to the form but I got an error global var author not defined.. and if I remove completely author  I got following error:  NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.author_id

Comment: becuase author is not null. And you shouldnt have removed author = request.user , you should have only removed it here instance=author

Comment: ok I did as you said but still having the same error: error: NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.author_id –

Comment: Thanks Aldarund for pointing me in the right direction. I fixed my view.